# Powershell - Select String - Export multiple Lines

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I´m searching for a `string` called "Please try again later" in a textfile.

How i can export the line with the match including n lines before the matching line?

Currently I use the following command to extract the matching line.

```
get-content "File.txt | select-string "Later"
```

Output should be like this (including ------------ if possible)

```
------
Sending: 250 <user@domain1.com>
SMTP Command: R-CPT TO:<user@domain2.com>
Sending: 451 Please try again later
------
```

Comment: Thanks for Editing C.B.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
get-content "File.txt" | select-string -Pattern 'Later' -CaseSensitive -Context 2
```

Comment: It is really awesome parameter. Why I didn't know it before

Comment: @Garath Because you don't spend time with `get-help get-content -full` ;)

Comment: This is embarrassing now, I have not read the manual. Thank you!